# Algebraic proof of Pascal Triangle

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

Can anyone explain the following:

1. ${n-1}\choose{k}$ = $\frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-1-k)!}$

Why was $(n-1-k)!$ added to equation 1?

2. ${n-1}\choose{k-1}$ = $\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}$

Why was $(n-k)!$ added to equation 2?

Comment: What are equations 1 and 2?

Comment: equation 1 refers to ${n-1}\choose{k}$ and equation 2 refers to ${n-1}\choose{k-1}$

Comment: Are you asking why $\binom{n-1}k=\frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-1-k)!}$?

Comment: If you were to apply the (defining) formula for binomial coefficients on $\binom{n-1}{k}$, what would you get?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos yes

Comment: How do you *define* $\binom nm$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos choose M things from N

Comment: It turns out that that's equal to $\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$.

Comment: What does adding a number to an equation mean? Can you point out the exact place where $(n-1-k)!$ was added to $\binom{n-1}k=\frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-1-k)!}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You agree that $$ \binom {n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$ for every non negative integers where $n\ge k$

The RHS of this formula involves a fraction whose top is a single factorial but the bottom is a product of two factorials one of which is $k!$ and the other one $(n-k)!$

Now change $n$ to $n-1$ and keep $k$ unchanged.

The formula changes to  $$ \binom {n-1}{k} = \frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-1-k)!}$$

Now if you change both $n$ to $n-1$ and $k$ to $k-1$ you get

$$ \binom {n-1}{k-1} = \frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-1-(k-1))!}$$

Which simplifies to $$ \binom {n-1}{k-1} = \frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}$$

Answer (score 1):

Very general hint for all problems of this form:

Write $$
\binom{u}{v} = \frac{u!}{v!(u-v)!}
$$
which is the general definition.

To prove formula 1, let $u = n-1$ and $v = k$; substitute and simplify.

To prove formula 2, let $u = n-1$ and $v = k-1$. Substitute and simplify.

Comment: Is $n-1$ an arbitrary number? Why are we substituting n-1 for u?

Comment: You're hoping to find a formula for ${n-1} \choose k$. You have a formula for $u \choose v$. If you replace $u$ with $n-1$ and $v$ with $k$, this *becomes* a formula for ${n-1} \choose k$; it probably won't be exactly the one you're aiming for, but a little cancellation will get you to that one. How do I know this is the right way to do these problems? Well, partly it's experience, and partly it's knowing how to apply a definition that's valid for all positive integers $u$ and $v$ to get a formula for a particular pair of values of $u$ and $v$ ; that's an instance of modus ponens, from logic.